# Which books do you recommend for me?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy, metaphilosophy

I read a lot about philosophy but it’s so huge that I stand confused. I am not sure which branch of philosophy suits me. I request your help.

1. I don’t believe in god or spirituality.
2. I want to live like a mathematician. Completely logical.
3. I question everything and don’t believe in phrases like ‘be optimistic’ , ‘be honest’, etc.
4. I know that I am a mammal just like all other mammals with an expiry date.
5. I want to keep myself healthy and find motivation to be successful at work.
6. I feel lonely sometimes and want to smoke or drink but I keep fighting back the urge. I loose self control as I don’t believe in promises or god.

Comment: "I want to live like a mathematician. Completely logical." Ahmad Chalabi earned a Ph.D. in math from the University of Chicago. He went on to be an Iraqi politician and, during the Iraq war, defrauded the CIA out of millions of dollars. Ted Kaczynski was a mathematician who sent mail bombs to people. Less well known is the other crazy mathematician Ted, Ted Streleski, who bludgeoned his thesis advisor to death (a fantasy of many a grad student I imagine). History is full of mathematicians with crazy ideas. (contintued ...)

Comment: Alexander Abian, a well-respected professor of mathematics. advocated blowing up the moon. Perhaps you idealize mathematicians too much. Let me offer a suggestion. To challenge yourself, study the opposite of all your ideas. You don't believe in religion? Study the great religious philosophers to better understand the nature of your disagreement. Just some idle thoughts based on your post. ps -- Kurt Gödel, the greatest logician of them all, died of starvation because he thought people were trying to poison him and refused to eat. Logic is no defense against an irrational universe.

Comment: Are you looking for a philosopher that espouses similar views, or just reading recommendations on philosophy (which need not be related to your views or challenge them in helpful ways)?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: I recommend The Story of Philosophy, by Will Durant (1926]. Notwithstanding the age of the work, it makes a lot of philosophers accessible to new readers.

Comment: Here's a reading list https://fallibleideas.com/books

Comment: @Conifold I would say both..philosopher or philosophy that would match my preferences

Answer (score 1):

Based on the anti-spirituality items (1,3,6), the interest in mathematics (2), the interest in self-help (5,6) and the interest in naturalism (4), you might look at some of the following tags on this site to see if the kind of questions are interesting:

1. [philosophy-of-science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science)
2. [philosophy-of-mathematics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-mathematics)
3. [philosophy-of-mind](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-mind)
4. [philosophy-of-religion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-religion)

Although the posts are organized by questions, the answers are what should be the most interesting.  They should suggest either links to other material to read or to hints on what to search for in places like Wikipedia, the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/) and the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/). The bibliographies in these online encyclopedia offer many resources to pursue once you have focused your attention on what you are most interested in.